# Datomic: what use cases can you name of its ability to handle time

Tags: datomic, temporal-database

The ability to look at your data in the past seems to be useful but it's not clear for me how to actually use it. What are the domains which benefit from this feature? Maybe there are some well-known use cases of 'temporality'?

Answer (score 5):

### Philosophy

It is quite hard, and not exactly necessary to list all of the domains. The answer to your question would be much more valuable if you provided domain(s) *you consider* Datomic for.

I would not think of time as just history or a feature, but rather a natural dimension that "we use" day to day in all domains whether it is software or not.

Having said that I can think of two domains where I considered and used Datomic in:

### Trading

You can see a simplified way Wall Street works and thinks just by looking at

[image]

One thing you notice here: *everything* is about time and "timing".

When any kind of financial analytics is needed, whether it is a future forecast or adjusting to a current market movement, time based thinking (read "queries, design, UI, etc..") is not just crucial, but natural.

Everybody works with bits, zeros and ones, and the ways you archive that thinking could be many, but if those bits already organized in a way that you tell them "show me quotes from X time to Y time, and slice them by trades that happen at this interval, and also show me firms that traded right before.." and those bits just *understand* you and provide that data is a big win. (vs. having your own implementation). Another interesting use for forecasting is Datomic's "[with](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/with)"

### Identity

People are identified differently everywhere: driver's license, passport, social security number, gym card, credit card, home address, etc.. A unique combination of these identifies a person, or sometimes a family, or sometimes a business, or sometimes a random group of humans, etc.

But what's interesting, these IDs keep changing over time.. constantly. Not only it is useful to always identify a person/group by *any* of this IDs "now", but also it is just necessary to be able to travel back, and sometimes forward: "what would the credit score of this person/business be if he/it had this credit card (account number)?"

### Philosophy

While above just two unrelated and narrow domains, they are real. And yes you can add a timestamp to all your DB records/documents/KV/column families/"what not", but all it'll give you is that: "timestamps" with no actual system **perception** of time. Datomic does give you this perception. And it does much more than that, but that is for another question.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that temporal view of the world is much more natural, I just find it redundant in cases where that history isn't used actively.

Comment: The domain are not so narrow. It is a new kind of thinking about databases. I've invented the same idea independently and have tried to promote. But, unfortunately, people don't think with the scale.

Comment: Eventually I come to a log-driven development in the code itself: everything is a log. And now I understand that I was right: it is a kind of thinking in more dimensions including time :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that most systems modeling real-world problems could benefit from the time model Datomic provides, simply because that model maps more closely to how things actually happen in the real world. See Rich Hickey's presentation: [Deconstructing-Database](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Deconstructing-Database).

More specifically, any application requiring versioning control or data-auditing capabilities could greatly benefit from Datomic's immutability because those capabilities are essentially built-in. Sometimes those capabilities are nice-to-have features, other times they are strong requirements (e.g. for Banking applications).

Comment: But for banking apps it's usually enough to save a time stamp with each transaction. What the ability to view the previous world state can add here? Also I'm interested if data history can not be only considered to be an archive but used more actively.